# How to pass multiple operators with value as an argument to the python method

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I have a function which validates the values of the column specified by the expression. The method will accept the user given expression as an argument to the function and check the same with entire column. User can define any expression. How can i pass the user define expression with multiple operator in a function. Here is my pseudo code.

```
def myFunction(list1, condition) :
    for value in list1:
        if condition :
            print("out of range")
        else :
            print("within range")

list1 =[1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 10]
myFunction(list1, (value >= 9) & (value < 1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass condition in that form, that isn't valid Python syntax. But you can make simple `lambda` function and pass it as a parameter:

```
def myFunction(list1, condition) :
    for value in list1:
        if condition(value):   # note we call here the lambda function
            print(value, "out of range")
        else :
            print(value, "within range")

list1 =[1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 10]

myFunction(list1, lambda value: (value >= 9) | (value < 1))
```

Prints:

```
1 within range
2 within range
3 within range
0 out of range
5 within range
10 out of range
```

EDIT: If `lambda` function isn't enough, you can make standard function with `def` and pass it to the `myFunction` as lambda.

Or (as @Solonotix mentioned in the comments), any object with `__call__` method).

Comment: To extend the edit Andrej provided, condition would just be any callable object. This means you could pass a lambda (anonymous callable object), a function (named callable object), or a class that has a properly defined `__call__` method. Otherwise, this is the solution you'd need to implement.

Comment: Thanks , I was trying without the lambda function, but seems it is not possible in python.